# Making Column Grid Filter Accept Complex Value In Magento

Tags: magento, filter, product

In Magento, there's a column in Product Grid/Table which is Name.

It only accepts or filter the table if you put the exact word/s.

Sample is "What Happened Last Night" (just an example)

If you put "What" it will filter correctly, if you add "Happened" it will still filter correctly but if you input "What Last" it will return 0 records unless there's a "What Last" record.

I have this code in the core itself.

```
 $this->addColumn('name',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_customNameFilter'),
    ));

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    if ($store->getId()) {
        $this->addColumn('name_search', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
            'type'  => 'text',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_customNameFilter'),
        ));
    }
```

Based on this link, [Grid filter for columns with complex values](https://www.atwix.com/magento/grid-filter-for-columns/)

I need to remove the index and adjust something or some files in which I'm totally lost as the author did not mention the file paths used.

Can anyone guide me on what file should I adjust or create if needed.

The Code above has the file path of

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php
```

What other files/modules should I adjust an what lines of code should I'd be looking at to attain this result.

I could not thank you enough for assisting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working solution for your case

```
protected function _customNameFilter($collection, $column)
{
if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
    return $this;
} else if (preg_match('/\s+/', $value)) {

        $tokens = explode(' ', $value);

    foreach($tokens as $token) {
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($column->getData('index'), array('like' => '%'.$token.'%'));
    }             
} else {   
    $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($column->getData('index'), array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
}
return $this;
}
```

this space tokenizer filter will also work with any other grid field.

Answer (score 0):

Atwix example will not solve the problem you described. If you want to make a filter smart enough to be on-the-fly tokenizer you will have to split the search string by spaces and add each token to where part of the query with "OR LIKE %'.$token.'%"

**Solution**

you will have to rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid in a local Module with following xml:

```
/app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml

<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_grid>Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

and add following methods into class

```
/app/code/local/Your/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Grid.php


class Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid {

        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
            $this->addColumn('name_search', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_customNameFilter'),
            ));
            return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }

        protected function _customNameFilter($collection, $column)
        {
            if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return $this;
            }

            $tokens = explode(' ', $value);

            $where = "LIKE '%".$value."%'";
            foreach($tokens as $token) {
                $where .= " OR LIKE '%".$token."%'";
            }

            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                "(at_name.value ?)"
            , $where);


            return $this;
        }
    }
```

And dont forget to rename Your_Module with your own namespace and add module description xml to /app/etc/modules/

you're welcome

Comment: Hi Sir. How About chaging it for the core itself and by not creating my own modules?

Comment: I updated the post to show you Sir the whole name add column

Comment: Making changes in core is not a good practice. It potentially breaks update-ability. It is up to you. You may use my filter_condition_callback method wherever you like.

Comment: Can you exist me on how to overwrite? This is just a test enviroment. I just used it to lean in depth of magento. Thanks

Comment: Sure, i can assist you. My answer is already a full guide on how overwrite. Ask if you have any further questions.

Comment: How do I do that If I want to use the core magento itself without overwriting?

`/app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml`

For the path above Sir. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: in this case you just edit app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php. add my new method  _customNameFilter somewhere at the bottom of class and use filter_condition_callback in your name column. Also make sure not to use index property for column where you use filter_condition_callback.

Comment: Is this normal, that the query returns count?
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `mgmx_catalog_product_entity` AS `e``
I just pasted the first few words of the query.

Comment: I think I Used the wrong Collection Query. Maybe I'll check other queries. thank You Sir